# Errors Received - Should I Install Visual C++ 2005 or 2010?

Tags: windows-7, visual-basic, runtime, runtime-error

I wanted to install  Rightload and setup required me to install Visual C++ 2005 runtime which i did, but after installation as tried to execute program, i got several error messages **(or was it runtime errors?)** and errors at addresses etc. everytime i tried to perform any action in application like these:

[image]

[image]

[image]

And this error kept me from using program always reappearing and i had to kill process in the end:

[image]

Just in case checked installed programs in **Control Panel** and saw this:

[image]

So i had already it installed and installed again? The sizes are different. Should i uninstall latest? Maybe i should reinstall all of them and instead install Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86)?

Comment: can you give some examples of the error messages?

Comment: @WalterMaier-Murdnelch Question updated!

Answer (score 0):

Delete installed Microsoft Visual packages with a Windows Installer CleanUp Utility http://majorgeeks.com/download.php?det=4459 .Then try to install again latest 2005/2008/2010 packages from ms site.